Weird text cursor on HTML Page in Microsoft Edge
I am using Edge and users can place a cursor on every text element of the web page. (SO has the same behavior)
How can I disable this feature on my site?
Example:


Is it possible you have Windows Narrator turned on?
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/appear-blinking-cursor-in-microsoft-edge/af2d91ee-1d3b-4a37-8c6c-1a02fc2dab2d
Pressing F7 should stop the caret browsing.

Thank you. Guess I should add the iamaretard-tag to my question ^_^

Check the <html>, <body>, or any other parent containers for the presence of the contenteditable attribute.
Here is an example where the content of every element is editable, and a text cursor will appear.


<body contenteditable="true">
  <header>
    <h1>Click this title</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>Click this heading</h2>
    <p>Click this paragraph</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Click this footer</p>
  </footer>
<body>




Thanks for fixing my post but this wasn't the solution. (checked my site and no, there is no contenteditable-attribute)

@Pagenotfound it was worth a shot. I did not know about the Windows narrator.
